# Restkit compatible version for Swift 2.3?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, afnetworking, restkit

I have updated code to Swift 2.3. I have `Restkit` in it. Its version was 2.7.0, but it was giving errors `use of undeclared identifier AFHTTPClient`. I downgraded it to version 2.5.0 and then 2.4.0, and still it is giving me Compiler Errors. What is the compatible version of Restkit [org.cocoapods.RestKit] for Swift 2.3?

Comment: You can use Alamofire. https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestKit 0.27 works with Swift 2.3 as well as Swift 3.0.

What errors were you getting?

What version of Cocoapods do you have?